# SQL Pivot records from Clocking System

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working with a clocking system where the clock-in and clock-out times are identified on separate rows - as seen below:

```
|ID | Clocking System | Employee | Date     | Time  | Clocking In / Out|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1  | System A        | John Doe | 1 Dec 20 | 05:30 | In               |
|2  | System B        | John Doe | 1 Dec 20 | 17:45 | Out              |
```

I would like to change this view where the clock-in and clock-out values are shown as a single single, such as:

```
|ID | Clocking System | Employee | Date     | Clocking In | Clocked Out |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1  | System A        | John Doe | 1 Dec 20 | 05:30       | 17:45       |
```

I would really appreciate any assistance.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know that the in/out records are *always* interleaved?  If not, explain what to do with the anomalies.

Comment: Research how to pivot data in SQL Server. You can pivot using the T-SQL `PIVOT` construct for instance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff
Apologies, I am fairly new to SQL. Interleaved? As in executed separately?
There is a case where the 'Out' field may be null. I have a stored procedure to cater for modifying records.

Comment: You must provide a way of identifying the employee other than just the name, eg. an Employee_ID. I'd make two separate queries for in and out times, then a join of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data has no anomalies, this is easily handled using `lead()`

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(time) over (partition by employee, date order by time) as checkout_time
      from t
     ) t
where in_out = 'In';
```

This assumes that there are no cases where there are missing in/out records or records of the same time in a row.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem when generating shifts from event data of ice hockey matches. The beginning and ending times for the shifts were mixed in with other events. There were multiple players and multiple games. The table `eventTable` was similar to this:

```
| player |   game   |    event    |  time_sec |
-----------------------------------------------
|   A    |  game-1  | shift-start |       10  |
|   B    |  game-1  | shift-start |       11  |
|   A    |  game-1  |    shot     |       12  |
|   A    |  game-1  |  shift-end  |       50  |
|   B    |  game-1  |    pass     |       55  |
|   B    |  game-1  |  shift-end  |       60  |
|   A    |  game-1  | shift-start |       90  |
|   A    |  game-1  |  shift-end  |      120  |
   ...        ...         ...           ...
|   X    |  game-n  |     ...     |     ...   |
```

I wanted to reshape the data so that it would be easy to answer questions like:

- How many shifts did player 1 have in game 1?
- Which shift was the longest (by player, by game)?
- What was the average duration of the shifts by player 1?

The desired output `shiftTable` was then:

```
| shift_number | player |  game  | shift_start | shift_end | duration |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|           1  |    A   | game-1 |      10     |      50   |     40   |
|           2  |    A   | game-1 |      90     |     120   |     30   |
|           1  |    B   | game-1 |      11     |      60   |     49   |
          ...     ...      ...         ...           ...        ...
|           n  |    X   | game-n |     ...     |     ...   |    ...   |
```

My solution was to create a subquery for each `shift_start` and `shift_end` with a new value called `shift_number` generated by the `row_number()` SQLITE function that incremented on a new shift event instance for each player and reset on every new game, shown below for `shift_start`:

```
SELECT
    row_number() OVER (
          PARTITION BY player, game
          ORDER BY time_sec) shift_number,
    player,
    game_name,
    time_sec AS shift_start
FROM
    eventTable
WHERE
    event = 'shift_start'
```

Which produced:

```
(subquery shift_start)                             
| shift_number | player |  game  | shift_start |
------------------------------------------------
|           1  |    A   | game-1 |      10     |
|           2  |    A   | game-1 |      90     |
|           1  |    B   | game-1 |      11     |

   
(subquery shift_end)
| shift_number | player |  game  | shift_end   |
------------------------------------------------
|           1  |    A   | game-1 |      50     |
|           2  |    A   | game-1 |     120     |
|           1  |    B   | game-1 |      60     |
```

When joined on `player, game, shift_number` produced the desired output table `shiftTable`.

The full query to produce `shiftTable` using SQLITE is as follows:

```
SELECT
    shift_number,
    player,
    game,
    shift_start,
    shift_end,
    shift_end - shift_start AS duration
FROM
    (SELECT
         row_number() OVER (
               PARTITION BY player, game
               ORDER BY time_sec) shift_number,
         player,
         game_name,
         time_sec AS shift_start
     FROM eventTable
     WHERE event = 'shift_start') 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
         row_number() OVER (
               PARTITION BY player, game
               ORDER BY time_sec) shift_number,
         player,
         game_name,
         time_sec AS shift_end
     FROM eventTable
     WHERE event = 'shift_end') 
USING (player, game, shift_number)
```

I used `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` because it was possible that a `shift_start` was missing its pair `shift_end` and vice-versa. This introduces a `NULL` for the missing pair, which I could then catch and deal with.

In `shiftTable` I felt it was better to pre-calculate duration for my workflow, and with the amounts of data I was dealing with meant that the space-time tradeoff didn't affect me either way.